# Usei o comando "chmod 700 /usr", e agora?

Tags: ubuntu

Não tenho mais acesso aos meus documentos e não consigo entrar como root pra desfazer essa besteira. Uso o Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Esta pergunta não far parte do [escopo do site](/help/on-topic)

Comment: Você pode fazer essa mesma pergunta na comunidade [**Ask Ubuntu**](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: @NoobSaibot Ele pode, se souber inglês.

Comment: @nmindz é uma pena, mas aqui tambem não é o local pra esse tipo de pergunta infelizmente.

Answer (score 1):

Se você tomou precauções de segurança quando instalou seu sistema operacional, deve ter *alterado ou criado uma senha para o usuário **root***. Considerando que tenha feito isso, ainda deve ser possível emitir o comando `su root` que irá logar você como `root` sem usar `/usr/bin/sudo`, o que deve funcionar.

Porém, se não for o caso, você ainda possui duas outras opções. Pode tentar logar como [*Single User Mode*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) (o que vai te logar em um shell diretamente como **root**) e a partir daí poderá desfazer essa "besteira".

Se nada disso funcionar, um outro computador ou outro disco/sistema operacional (no caso, Linux) será necessário para te ajudar. Você vai precisar adicionar o disco afetado no sistema de destino, bootar e logar no sistema operacional saudável e funcional, e a partir dali irá utilizar a ferramenta `chroot` para alterar o caminho base do seu shell para dentro da partição onde a sua instalação do Ubuntu com problemas está.

Isso permitirá que você corrija as permissões (uma vez que o `sudo` irá usar as permissões da shell em que foi lançado, portanto você não precisa ser root do *seu* Ubuntu). Também permite que altere a senha do seu `root` (como precaução) para caso algo mais saia errado. Você pode aprender mais sobre [chroot clicando aqui](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Base/pt-br#Fazendo_chroot). É a documentação de instalação do Gentoo, mas é em português e pode te fornecer algumas instruções de como fazê-lo.

Lembrando que se optar pelo último método, uma vez que acessar sua partição pelo outro computador, recomendo fortemente que **FAÇA BACKUP DOS SEUS DADOS PESSOAIS**, pois se cometer erros nessa etapa pode causar danos irreparáveis a seus dados.